# Preserving order when label encoding

Tags: python, encoding

I am trying to label my data as follows:

```
>  Frequency.   Encoded Frequency
>     0 Hz                 1
>     0.5 Hz               2
>     1.0 Hz               3
>     1.5 Hz               4
>     2.0 Hz               5
```

But when I use the labelencoder() function I get this - a variation in the encoded frequency:

```
Output:    
Frequency.       Encoded Frequency
    0 Hz                 1
    0.5 Hz               2
    1.0 Hz               3
    1.5 Hz               5
    2.0 Hz               4
```

What I want to achieve is a structured numerical order for the values as this makes my processing further down in my code easier ( for me) to understand.
I have placed my code below:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure

#############################################################################
############################ Functions ######################################
#############################################################################


def frequency_labels(frequency):
    L = []
    for w, f2 in enumerate(s_frequency):
        for q in noise:
         freq_label = " {:.2f} Hz".format(f2)
         L.append(freq_label)
         q = q+1
        
    return L

def time_labels(time):
    H = []
    for r,t in enumerate(time):
        h = " {} s".format(t)
        H.append(h)
    return H

def gaussian_noise(increment,len_time):
    mean = 0
    standard_deviation = np.arange(0.5,2.2,increment) 
    ## want 8096 different noise signals of different standard deviations
    sd = standard_deviation.reshape(len(standard_deviation),1)
    noise = np.empty((len(sd), (len_time), (1)), dtype=np.float64)
     
    for t, value in enumerate(sd):
         
        noise[t] = np.random.normal(mean,value,len_time).reshape(len_time,1)
        
    return noise

#############################################################################
############################ Variables ######################################
#############################################################################

s_frequency = np.arange(0,60,0.5) # range of frequencies
fs = 200
time = np.arange(0,2-(1/fs),(1/fs))
amplitude = np.empty((len(time)), dtype=np.float16)
len_time = len(time)
len_frequency = len(s_frequency)
array = np.empty((len(time)), dtype=np.float16)
increment = 0.1  #0.00021
k = 0 



#############################################################################
##################### Calling Functions #####################################
#############################################################################

noise = gaussian_noise(increment,len_time)
training_labels = frequency_labels(s_frequency)
H = time_labels(time)

new_array = np.empty((len(s_frequency)*(len(noise)),len(time)),dtype=np.float64)

#############################################################################
######################Creation of Signals ###################################
#############################################################################


for true_freq in s_frequency:
       
      amplitude = np.sin(2*np.pi*true_freq*time).reshape(len(time),1)
      amplitude = np.add(noise,amplitude).reshape(len(noise),len(time))
   
    
      for r in range(17):
        average = float(min(amplitude[r,:]) + max(amplitude[r,:]))/2
        rangev = float(max(amplitude[r,:]) - min(amplitude[r,:]))/2
        new_array[k+r] = (amplitude[r,:] - average)/rangev

        
      
      k = k + 17
        
        
training_labels = np.array(training_labels).reshape((len(s_frequency)*len(noise)),)  

#############################################################################
############# Creation of DataFrame of Labels for Signals ###################
#############################################################################

frequency_table = pd.DataFrame(training_labels)
frequency_table.columns = ['Frequency']
#le = LabelEncoder()
oe = OrdinalEncoder()
frequency_encoded = oe.fit_transform(frequency_table['Frequency'])
frequency_table['Encoded Frequency'] = frequency_encoded 
onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
frequency_encoded = frequency_encoded.reshape(len(frequency_encoded), 1)
onehot_encoded = onehot_encoder.fit_transform(frequency_encoded)
#frequency_table['One Hot Encoded Frequency'] = onehot_encoded
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to rank order the frequencies.  You can do that but first you need to cast them as numbers to avoid dictionary ordering.

```py
frequency_table['Encoded Frequency'] = (
    frequency_table
    ['Frequency']
    .str[:-3]
    .astype(float)
    .rank(method='dense')
    .astype(int)
)
```